# Can a course title be similar to a book name or a course at other university?

Tags: teaching, coursework

Is there any issue with using a course title that is similar to a book title or a course at other university, or it would be better to have a unique name?

Comment: Could you provide some examples? In most universities I am familiar with, course titles are ... simply descriptive and bland. Without changing this convention, it would be extremely hard to come up with something that is guaranteed not to be also a book title, let alone a course name at another university. To name a few examples: "Data Structures". "Programming Languages". "Introduction to Computer Science". "Mathematics for Computer Science". "Human-Computer Interaction". "Operating System Basics".

Comment: How many books and courses are titled "Calculus", "Mathematical Analysis" or "Topology"?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper let's say "Calculus for scientists and engineers"

Comment: @ThomasLee your example seems to be a perfectly legitimate way title for a course that covers calculus for scientists and engineers - I presume this is to distinguish it from "calculus for English majors" and "calculus for real mathematicians"? If your department does indeed offer three different calculus courses, an informative title seems entirely appropriate. No need for originality here.

Comment: It might be confusing though if an introductory course to analog black-and-white photography was titled "50 shades of grey" ...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the question here hinges upon how specific the book title is. If you could not repeat book titles, there would be hundreds if not thousands of calculus and organic chemistry courses in violation, for instance.

However, if the title of the book in question is *Sprockets and Doohickeys: A History of Widgets in 20th Century Television*, you might want to find an alternate title do the course. Technically it's not a copyright violation, but it does betray a lack of independent thought on the part of the instructor in a specialized course.

Answer (score 7):

I don't see any issue.  There is no copyright issue since a title would not generally be protected by copyright (see [here](http://copyright.gov/circs/circ34.pdf)).  It doesn't strike me as plagiarism unless the course title is especially unique and you are passing off its creation as your own.

The only possible problem I could see is if it is for an online course that is still be offered at another online source.  This could create confusion for students searching for that particular class.

For most courses there are not a huge number of informative course title one could plausibly use.

Answer (score 5):

As others have commented, using a course title that's identical to the title of an existing course or book does not raise issues of copyright infringement, at least in the United States. However, it may raise issues of *trademark* infringement, e.g., if your course title is or contains a protected trademark, as in "Quantum Mechanics For Dummies".

See [here](http://www.mmblawfirm.com/publications/articles/franchise/67.htm) for a related discussion.

Answer (score 3):

There is a very famous introductory CS book named "Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs" (SICP) by Harold Abelson, Gerald Jay Sussman, Julie Sussman in MIT. This is known as one of the best books ever written about introductory computer science: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_and_Interpretation_of_Computer_Programs

I don't know if other universities have any similar courses (they probably do) but University of California, Berkeley has a course with exactly same name, **twice**. CS 61A and CS 61AS are named after this book probably due to legacy reasons:
http://cs61a.org/ http://www.cs61as.org/

Considering that both MIT and Berkeley are top-notch universities in CS (arguably top-3) it convinces me that it is okay to give name to your course after a good textbook in your field, written in a different university.

Comment: If you use said textbook, probably no problem. If not (and you do something very different), it *might* be (considered) misleading.

Comment: @vonbrand True. In this very case I brought up, CS 61A uses a Berkeley edited edition of SICP (because SICP was written for Scheme, but CS 61A uses Python). So, you can say the textbook is a different edition of the original textbook; but definitely curriculum (topics covered) is just the same. In fact, homework assignments are coming from SICP (edited for Python) and there are allusions to SICP characters (Alyssa P. Hacker etc...) in exams/homeworks too. Thus, it is very explicit that CS 61A is just the class version of the textbook. If class is not related to textbook it would be misleading.